# Notation for set of elements where each element can only be 1 of 3 possible values and each possible value includes 50 elements

Tags: notation

I'd like some help with math notation for the following scenario:

P is a set of all m. m can be either X_a or X_b or X_c. There are M unique m's for each X_a or X_b or X_c

Example: P is a set of all marbles (m). Marbles can be of size 1 or 2 or 3 There are 50 marbles for each size, each marble being totally unique

I'm thinking:

```
ma , mb , mc = 1, 2, 3

|ma or mb or mc | = 50

P = {m| m = ma or mb or mc }
```

Is there a better way? Thank you!

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to do with this, but how about something like $M$ is the set of marbles. There is a size function $s$ from the set of marbles to the set $\{1,2,3\}$, that is, $s:M\rightarrow\{1,2,3\}$. Let $A_j$ be the set of marbles of size $j$, that is $A_j=\{m\in M\vert s(m) = j\}$. Then $\lvert A_j\rvert=50$ for all $j\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Hi @WillOrrick Thank you for your  response! Yes you got exactly what I'm trying to get at! I've edited the post to add a rephrasing of the marbles example.

Comment: @WillOrrick Your answer makes me think it should be a set of sets. M is a set of Aj. s: m -> {1,2,3}. Aj = {m | s(m) = j}. |Aj| = 50. Is it necessary then to add the "for all j E {1,2,3} " ? Thanks for your patience

Comment: As far as I can see, your post has not been edited since your comment. In the notation $f:A\rightarrow B$ the symbols $A$ and $B$ represent sets and $f$ represents a function taking an element of $A$ is input and producing an element of $B$ as output. So if $a\in A$, then $f(a)\in B$. In the marbles example, $s$ is the function that takes a marble (or perhaps a marble ID number) as input, and produces a size label as output. So in my scheme the elements of $M$ are marbles, not sets of marbles. The sets $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ are subsets of $M$, not elements of $M$.

Comment: @WillOrrick Ya, I tried to but couldn't come up with anything significantly different. So your full solution (let j be the different sizes, and r be the number of marbles (m) for each j. 
M = {m}. s : M→{j}. A_j={m∈M | s(m)=j}. |A_j|=r for all j. 
I prefer this solution than the one I've accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, but ignoring your suggested symbolisation, what you want is $$P=\{s_1,s_2,s_3,\ldots,s_n,m_1,m_2,m_3,\ldots,m_n,l_1,l_2,l_3,\ldots,l_n\}.$$

In your example, the $3n$ elements of $P$ are all distinct from one another—i.e., set $P$ has cardinality $3n$—and $n=50.$

---

**Addendum**
OP: *I do like the solution but it doesn't give much flexibility to adding more than one size (other than your s, m, l. Is there a way to add such?*

Sure, choose either \begin{align}P=\{&\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\ldots,\alpha_n,\\&\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3,\ldots,\beta_n,\\&\ldots,\\&μ_1,μ_2,μ_3,\ldots,μ_n\}.\end{align} or \begin{align}P=\{&x_{11},x_{12},x_{13},\ldots,x_{1n},\\&x_{21},x_{22},x_{23},\ldots,x_{2n},\\&\dots,\\&x_{m1},x_{m2},x_{m3},\ldots,x_{mn}\}.\end{align}

Comment: Yup, you understand it correctly! Ooo a very straight to the point solution, I like it. Thank you @ryang !

Comment: I do like the solution but it doesn't give much flexibility to adding more than one size (other than your s, m, l. Is there a way to add such? PS.  I did try to upvote but I'm a noobie

Comment: Well done! Thank you!!